# Possible to create a custom reference for Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was wondering if it was possible to create a custom reference to be added into visual studio and if there were any guides, I can't seem to find any tutorials online. (I may be searching for the wrong thing)

But what I'm trying to do is to create a reference to allow programmers to have some sort of dropdown list whilst typing their code besides the already existing library.

Or is it possible to add custom words/strings into it?

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're talking about is adding custom macros/snippets to Intellisense or something like an addin for visual studio.

Check out Tools --> Code Snippet Manager

This is the same thing as doing prop   to auto complete snippets.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514413/using-a-code-snippet-for-inotifypropertychanged/30919919#30919919) is another answer with a good explanation.  I believe Re-Sharper can accomplish this as well.

Is this the sort of functionality you were going for?