# Is there a shortcut for when I declare the get; set; of a variable but with a PropertyChanged?

Tags: c#

In C# I would like to code this for all my Static variable:

```
public static int Secs {
  get {
    return secs;
  }
  set {
    secs = value;
    PropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

Is there any shortcut way to achieve the same thing.  Sorry I don't mean a shortcut way to write it like typing "prop".  I mean some way that all of the above could be written in one line.

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514413/using-a-code-snippet-for-inotifypropertychanged

Comment: Do you mean a some snippet for generation this code or a some more elegant and compact way for sending `PropertyChanged` and setting `value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in Visual Studio to generate as you mentioned above , but you can generate get; and set; with type **`"prop"`** or **`"propfull"`** and then press tab twice. That will generate the following.

**`public TYPE Type { get; set; }`**

But if you really want to achieve, as michael mentioned follow **[`Resharper way`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514413/using-a-code-snippet-for-inotifypropertychanged)**