# Adding custom items to intellisense in Visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have some requirements in making the intellisense customizable. Is this possible?

I want to add a custom item into the dropdown that gets triggered when "." (period) is pressed. 
Also any information regarding code completion would be very much appreciated.

Basically, i'm looking for something like: 
A doubletab press after typing "for" would generate the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {

        }.
```

Can we have custom items to insert different code snippets as above?

Comment: If i am not wrong you want your own snippets for C# ? Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956638/custom-code-snippets-in-intellisense

Comment: Yes.. I want to create my own items in the Intellisense dropdown menu and then insert custom code snippets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms165394(v=vs.100).aspx) have complete steps to do your custom code snippet.

I have developed one sample snippet intellisense for you. Just open the folder path for snippet in file explorer and paste your custom snippet file here.

**Step 1:**
[image]

**Step2:**

Created my custom "janty" snippet file and saved file as .Snippet extension.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>janty</Title>
            <Shortcut>janty</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for if statement</Description>
            <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
                <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>expression</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Expression to evaluate</ToolTip>
                    <Default>true</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[Hello Jayanti ($expression$)
    {
        $selected$ $end$
    }]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

**Step: 3**

Test the snippet using short key "janty". Its working.
[image]

Its simple approach.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Kartik, If the post helped you please do not forgot to mark it and upvote.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is possible. Have a look at [this MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx).

Here a little Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>Hello World</Title>
      <Author>Myself</Author>
      <Description>Says a string to the world.</Description>
      <Shortcut>hello</Shortcut> <!-- This is your intellisense Shortcut -->
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>sayValue</ID>
          <ToolTip>Replaced with what you want.</ToolTip>
          <Default>"Hello"</Default>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="CSharp">
        <![CDATA[
          valueToSay = $sayValue$;
          Console.WriteLine(valueToSay);
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

How to install:

1. Save this somewhere
2. Go in your VS to `Tools` -> `Code Snipptes Manager`
3. Choose `Import`
4. Choose your *(in Step 1 saved)* file