# Custom code snippet not showing before first "using" statement

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

This custom code snippet used to show up when typing `CR` at the top of a
C# source file in Visual Studio 2013:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Insert a Copyright notice</Title>
            <Shortcut>CR</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for the Copyright notice comment</Description>
            <Author>Pierre Arnaud</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
              <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Code Language="csharp">
                <![CDATA[//  Copyright © 2015, EPSITEC SA, CH-1400 Yverdon-les-Bains, Switzerland$end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

In Visual Studio 2015, the code snippet `CR` does not show up in the
suggestion if I place the cursor before the first `using` statement.
The only suggestions which show up are the two Visual Studio provided
`extern` and `using` snippets.

Any idea if I have to update the XML of this snippet for this to work
again?

EDIT: I opened an issue on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1846931/code-snippet-not-showing-at-start-of-c-source-file).

Comment: So I am not the only one experiencing this issues and explains why my devs not following practice.

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956638/custom-code-snippets-in-intellisense

Comment: @StefanW. I am not using ReSharper in my case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One work around I did discover is to move the cursor to the top of the code file and then press Ctrl+K, Ctrl+S (the surround with snippet shortcut).  This brings up the code snippets, including the Copyright one I have locally.  This can be selected.  Not a great solution but it works until a fix is in place.